# JSF command button is not compile

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Hi im studying JSF 2.0
Using tomcat 6.0.26

When a start a simple page the h:commandButton doesnt displayed, and the html source in browser display `<h:commandbutton value="Click (Good)" action="successful-test"></h:commandbutton>`

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head><title>JSF 2.0: Server Test</title>
<link href="./css/styles.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</h:head>
<h:body>
<div align="center">
<table border="5">
  <tr><th class="title">JSF 2.0: Server Test</th></tr>
</table>
<p/>

<h:form>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Valid action</legend>
  Click button. You should get success page.<br/>
  <h:commandButton value="Click (Good)" action="successful-test" />
</fieldset>
<p/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Invalid action</legend>
  Click button. You should get error message about not being 
  able to find matching navigation case.<br/>
  <h:commandButton value="Click (Bad)" action="bogus-outcome" />
</fieldset>
</h:form>

</div></h:body></html>
```

the html code after tomcat running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head><title>JSF 2.0: Server Test</title>
<link href="./css/styles.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</h:head>
<h:body>
<div align="center">
<table border="5">
  <tr><th class="title">JSF 2.0: Server Test</th></tr>
</table>
<p/>

<h:form>
<fieldset>

  <legend>Valid action</legend>
  Click button. You should get success page.<br/>
  <h:commandButton value="Click (Good)" action="successful-test" />
</fieldset>
<p/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Invalid action</legend>
  Click button. You should get error message about not being 
  able to find matching navigation case.<br/>

  <h:commandButton value="Click (Bad)" action="bogus-outcome" />
</fieldset>
</h:form>

</div></h:body></html>
```

what happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, nothing happened. There's something wrong with your configuration. Tomcat is not parsing the JSF code at all and just returning it verbatim.

Please post your web.xml configuration.

Comment: apparently the problem is tomcat. i have changed to tomcat 7 and runs ok